# use google sheets and script to send email

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying, with a script, to send an email once a cell is edited. Assuming I have the following sheet, I would like to send an email containing keyword2 (cell a3) only when `ok` is written on cell b3. the same, if I write `ok` on cell `b2`, I would like to send an email with `keyword` (cell a2)

```
| COL A      | COL B  |
| keyword    |        |
| keyword2   |  ok    |
```

I used this script and was able to send an email, but it takes both rows, I only want the script to take the row where the `ok` is adiacent (not all rows)

can you please help me out and address me on how I can solve this?

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
/**
 * add trigger for onedit - 
 * see menu -> Resouces -> Current project's triggers
 */
function Initialize() {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification")
        .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
        .onEdit()
        .create();

};


/**
 * 
 */


function sendNotification(e) {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var keyword = row[0]; // Colonna A
        var URL = row[3]; // Colonna D

        if ("B2" == e.range.getA1Notation() || "B3" == e.range.getA1Notation()) {
            if (e.value == "ok") {



                //Define Notification Details
                var recipients = "email@example.com";
                var subject = "Update" + e.range.getSheet().getName();
                var body = "cell " + keyword;

                //Send the Email
                MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you're only check for the word 'Ok' but you haven't made a variable to store any cell that contains 'ok' and then display all information from that variable if it contains 'ok'.